# Complex key constraint: allow only if uuid is new or another column matches

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, constraint

For my use case I am trying to get something like this to work with Azure Data Factory (ADF)

but I'm also interested in this question from a theoretical perspective. Is it possible to do something like this in a normal SQL engine like postgres?

I want to disallow inserts based on this key: (non_unique_id, timestamp) where timestamp is a unique value for that pair.

for example:

### data to insert:

```
non_unique_id: 0cf6c19c14
timestamp: 1970-01-01 00:00:01
```

### case 1 ALLOWED

before insert:

```
select non_unique_id, timestamp from tbl where non_unique_id = 0cf6c19c14;

0 results
```

### case 2 ALLOWED

before insert:

```
select non_unique_id, timestamp from tbl where non_unique_id = 0cf6c19c14;

0cf6c19c14, 1970-01-01 00:00:01
0cf6c19c14, 1970-01-01 00:00:01
0cf6c19c14, 1970-01-01 00:00:01
...
```

### case 3 NOT ALLOWED

before insert:

```
select non_unique_id, timestamp from tbl where non_unique_id = 0cf6c19c14;

0cf6c19c14, 2038-01-19 03:14:05
0cf6c19c14, 2038-01-19 03:14:05
0cf6c19c14, 2038-01-19 03:14:05
...
```

Of course there are other columns but this illustrates the simplest cases

Comment: So, the constraint should be something like `COUNT(non_unique_id) = 0 OR COUNT(non_unique_id || timestamp) > 1` ? AFAIK, very few DBMS implements declarative constraints (beside candidate-, foreign-key) at table level. It should not be to hard implementing it with a procedural construct like a trigger though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a normalisation issue as timestamp is functionally dependent on `non_unique_id`.

So there should be another table with primary key `non_unique_id` and the corresponding timestamp.

In SQL Server/Azure SQL Database you *can* enforce this with an [indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15) though.

Create a view with schema binding and definition

```
SELECT non_unique_id,
       timestamp,
       COUNT_BIG(non_unique_id) AS Count
FROM   dbo.YourTable
GROUP  BY non_unique_id,
          timestamp
```

and then put a unique clustered index on column `non_unique_id` in the view.

Comment: That's elegant. If you insert directly into the table, does the view enforce the constraint anyhow?

Comment: Yes - inserting into the table will automatically maintain the view in the same query plan and validate the constraints on it

Comment: That's cool. Thanks